# Hide Friendly URL from in Search Result - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

We have a SharePoint 2013 Publishing Site in which we would like to **hide few pages from search** result. Tried below options and non of them are working.

Tried Options:

1. **Hide physical URLs from search** - Set to "Yes" (Page Property)
2. **Hide from Internet Search Engines** - Set to "Yes"
3. **Exclude from sitemap and hide from Search Engines** - Selected (Edit SEO Property)
4. Add Page as "**Disallow**" Entry in **robots.txt** file.

   Note: Cant use the "Search Result Removal" and "Query Rules" are not an option as Content Contributors don't have access to Central Admin. They can only manage Pages. Any direction will be of great help.

Comment: the challenge is that search engine crawl your page, you can do two things 1- password protect the page OR 2- make isolated sub domain instance that is not submitted to SEO and should not have link to or from other pages. Number 1 is more secure, number 2 no garanti

Comment: cant make password protected page (we should be able to access it directly). but hide it from search result.